# How to make a scrollview and layout it with both absolutelayout and stacklayout (Xamarin Forms)?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Having a lot of problems making a simple scrollview and inside it have both absolutelayout and stacklayouts. The stacklayout works fine but the image/labels that are controlled by an absolutelayout does not get the correct size. (I gather the image and all the labels from my codepage).

This is my current code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>

  <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 0.0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
    <AbsoluteLayout>

        <Image  Aspect = "AspectFill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 0.0, 1, 0.5" 
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name = "image" />

        <Button BackgroundColor = "Red"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.0, 0.45, 0.5, 0.15"  />

        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 1.0, 1, 0.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  >

        <Label x:Name = "title" />
        <Label x:Name = "date" />
        <Label x:Name = "text" />

        </StackLayout>

    <AbsoluteLayout>
  </ScrollView>

<AbsoluteLayout>
```

With this current code the image does not take 0.5 of the screen in height. It is much longer. I have tried to add a HeightRequest ="700" on the AbsolueLayout and then the image positions itself correctly but then the scrollview does not work even when the label text is longer than the screen.

Comment: Problem is that your Absolute Layout just doesn't have enough information to calculate its size properly neither by using its parent size nor by using its children sizes. Can you tell more about your problem so maybe we could suggest better layout for you.

Comment: @Artur Shamsutdinov Yeah sure. WIth this current code the image and the button that is controlled by the absolutelayout does not get the right size. they get bigger then they are supposed to. If I add a heightrequest of the screen device height inside the absolutelauout they get the correct size but the page is not scrollable then.

Comment: Why not use Grid instead of absolute layout? just make the column and rows definition with the right ratio.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez can you give us a wireframe of what you need?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/OwlzD this is what i am trying to achieve. so that i scroll the entire page and the image gets layed out the way i want.

Comment: @OriPrice Ok! I have never worked with a grid before. WOuld be awesome if you could show me an example

Comment: What is your desired output? could you add a sketch of how would you like to layout the image, button and the stack layout?

Comment: @OriPrice http://imgur.com/a/ACvZB like this if i understand correctly

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should give you what you want.
The grid has two equal rows (due to the use of "*"), one with the image and one containing the button and the stacklayout.
Button height will be 50dp and is aligned to the top right corner of the row using horizontal and vertical alignment properties.
You can change the ratio between the rows by putting a number before *. For example:

```
  <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
```

Above snippet will divide the rest of the space to 3 which will give the image 2/3 of the space and 1/3 to the stacklayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Rumble.Client.Page1">
  <ScrollView>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Image  Aspect = "AspectFill" Grid.Row="0" x:Name = "image" />
      <Button BackgroundColor="Red"  Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalAlignment="End" VerticalAlignment="Start"  />
      <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
        <Label x:Name = "title" />
        <Label x:Name = "date" />
        <Label x:Name = "text" />
      </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want the scroll to work you'll have to set it's row to auto so it will take as much space as it needs instead of screen height limit:

```
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Code runs and works but the image still gets very big. If I write   <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition> instead then it gets even bigger

Comment: Sure, with the current code the image height is according to the content. you can set HeightRequest on the image to limit its height.

Comment: Do you have knowledge when it comes to JSON and adding it to xamarin forms btw? If so i just created a new thread if you want to check it out :)